# Dereferencing a pointer to a null pointer?

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a robust LinkedList in c, and one of the issues I am dealing with is initialization.

`struct node* list = malloc(sizeof(node))`

is an obvious way to initialize the LList, but it initializes the `head` element's `value` to 0, which is not exactly what I want.  A newly initialized LList should not have any nodes in it.  Instead, I'd like to do something like this:

```
struct node* list = NULL;
```

to create a LList, and then add elements with:

```
add(&list, 1);
add(&list, 2);
```

that would basically dereference `&list`, test to see if it is `NULL`, and if so do X otherwise do Y.  However, obviously I am seg faulting, and am wondering if it is because I am dereferencing a pointer to a null pointer?

**add()**

```
  8 void add(struct node** headRef, int value) {
  9   struct node* node = *headRef;
 10   struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
 11 
 12   new_node->value = value;
 13   new_node->next = NULL;
 14 
 15   if (node == NULL) {
 16     node = malloc(sizeof(node));
 17     node = new_node;
 18   } else {
 19 
 20     while (node->next != NULL) {
 21       node = node->next;
 22     }
 23 
 24     node->next = new_node;
 25   }
 26 }
```

Thanks

Comment: How can we possibly tell if you don't show the code where the seg fault is happening? If you dereference `&list` you will get `list`. Which is fine. What you can't do is then dereference `list`.

Comment: Well, you might know if dereferencing a pointer to a null pointer causes a seg fault, for one.  **EDIT: Thanks for the edit Alan, that was all I was asking... whether one can dereference a pointer to a null pointer.**

Comment: I can post code, update pending...

Comment: That's implementation specific. Dereferencing a NULL pointer is Undefined Behaviour. But in most cases, yes you will get a seg fault.

Comment: If you really mean a pointer to a null pointer, dereferencing it gives you the value null, with type pointer.

Comment: `struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));` should be `sizeof(new_node)`.

Comment: @zelliott if you're lucky, the standard doesn't define what happens if you do dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: And where is the seg fault happening? Doesn't look like it is in the `add` function you have shown. Nevertheless, the `add` implementation is not right. There are a number of errors. Including at least the follwoing. 1. In the `NULL` case you `malloc` and then throw away the result on the next line - memory leak results. 2. `headref` never gets updated so the head of your list will always be NULL. Somewhere you need `*headRef = new_node`. These errors probably cause a seg fault somewhere else in your code due to the NULL head of the list.

Comment: Damn, good catches, will update and see if problem is fixed.  EDIT.  Yeah the `*headRef = new_node` change fixed it... thank you!

Comment: @John3136 no, it was correct originally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has 3 problems:

```
node = malloc(sizeof(node));
node = new_node;
```

Firstly you malloc the wrong number of bytes. Use the pattern `node = malloc(sizeof *node);` .

Secondly this leaks memory: you point `node` at a freshly allocated block of memory. Then you point `node` at the object `new_node` is pointing at. This leaves no pointers to the allocated block.

Thirdly, `node` is a local variable to your function so this change is not seen by code outside your function.

I think you meant the entire function to be something like:

```
void add(struct node** headRef, int value)
{
// Make the new node
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;

// If the list is empty then make the new node be the first node
    if ( *headRef == NULL ) 
        *headRef = new_node;

// Otherwise put this node on the end of the list
    else for ( struct node *ptr = *headRef; ; ptr = ptr->next )
    {
         if ( ptr->next == NULL )
         {
              ptr->next = new_node;
              break;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is just a mechanism to access memory. Different types of pointers has different access mechanisms. Integer pointer reads 4 bytes while character pointer reads only one when you deference it.

For storing something, You need to allocate memory. Once you allocate memory, you can access it using different pointers.
When you write :

```
  new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node))
```

it means that you are allocating some memory and accessing it using new_node pointer.

When you write:

```
   node=new_node
```

it means that node will point to the same memory new_node is currently referring.You dont need to allocate memory to node since you are just accessing the already allocated memory using it.

```
void add(struct node** headRef, int value) {
    struct node* node = *headRef;
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));//Always mention datatype rather than mentioning a particular value;

    new_node->value = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (node == NULL) {
      //node = malloc(sizeof(node)); //Not required as you are just accessing the pre-allocated memory;

      *headRef = new_node; //Change the actual pointer rather than the local one;
    } else {

      while (node->next != NULL) {
        node = node->next;
      }

      node->next = new_node;
    }
 }
```